# AzureDevops Pipeline Templates From Folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use templates in my pipeline that are in the same project folder but on Validate yam and run pipeline gives me an error

> /templates/transform-settings.yml (Line: 1, Col: 1): A sequence was not expected

Here is the part of azure-pipelines.yml and template:

```
 imagePullSecret: ' fd bfgbgf '
  dockerfilePath: '**/Dockerfile'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  testVar: 'test'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection: ""

stages:
  - template: templates/transform-settings.yml
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      displayName: Build
      pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      steps:
      - task: Docker@2
        inputs:
          command: buildAndPush
          repository: $(imageRepository)
          dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
          containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
```

.... and template:

```
- stage: TransformFiles
  displayName: TransformFiles
  variables:
    - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'development') }}:
      - group: dev-secrets
      - name: testVar
        value: 'dev'
      - name: ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection
        value: $(psql-conn-str-dev)
    - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'qa') }}:
      - group: qa-secrets
      - name: testVar
        value: 'qa'
  jobs:
    - job: Transform_AppSettings
      steps:      
      - bash: echo "===== Transforming appsettings.json for $(variables['Build.SourceBranchName']) environment ====="
        displayName: 'File Transform'
      - task: FileTransform@1
        inputs:
          folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
          fileType: 'json'
          targetFiles: 'appsettings.json'
      - upload: appsettings.json
        artifact: appsettings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /templates/transform-settings.yml (Line: 1, Col: 1): A sequence was not expected

Based on your yaml sample, the issue is related to the format of the YAML template.

To solve this issue, you need to add the **stages:** field at the top of the template YAML file.

For example:

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
stages:
  - template: templates/transform-settings.yml
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      displayName: Build
      pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      steps:
      - task: Docker@2
        inputs:
          command: buildAndPush
          repository: $(imageRepository)
          dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
          containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
```

**transform-settings.yml**

```
stages:
- stage: TransformFiles
  displayName: TransformFiles
  variables:
    - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'development') }}:
      - group: dev-secrets
      - name: testVar
        value: 'dev'
      - name: ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection
        value: $(psql-conn-str-dev)
    - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'qa') }}:
      - group: qa-secrets
      - name: testVar
        value: 'qa'
  jobs:
    - job: Transform_AppSettings
      steps:      
      - bash: echo "===== Transforming appsettings.json for $(variables['Build.SourceBranchName']) environment ====="
        displayName: 'File Transform'
      - task: FileTransform@1
        inputs:
          folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
          fileType: 'json'
          targetFiles: 'appsettings.json'
      - upload: appsettings.json
        artifact: appsettings
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [YAML template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#stage-reuse).

Comment: Thanks, Kevin Lu-MSFT, but now I lose my variables in the template, somehow I don't have access